# How to properly finish a (piped) python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this litte example code snippet which basically does a `ls | grep foo` with python subprocesses:

```py
import subprocess
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("always")

lhs = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
rhs = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "foo"], stdin=lhs.stdout)
lhs.stdout.close()
rhs.communicate()
```

At the end, I get a warning that says:

"/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:942: ResourceWarning: subprocess 1519 is still running"

Since my code is equivalent to https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline, I am quite sure to do the right thing. So why is this warning generated or what can I do to prevent python from complaining there (besides suppressing warnings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing <s>`lhs.communicate()`</s>`lhs.wait()` (`communicate` also waits for the process to finish, but `wait` is more self explanatory),

```
lhs = subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
rhs = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "foo"], stdin=lhs.stdout)
lhs.stdout.close()
rhs.communicate()
lhs.wait()
```

but IMO you should use higher level functions like `subprocess.run`

Comment: This is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, but it waits for process to finish and I just discovered that you there's also a wait method :D

Comment: Yes, the `lhs.stdout.close()` is recommended so that `lhs` can receive a SIGPIPE if `rhs` exits, so `lhs.wait()` is better.

Comment: Okay, I could try lhs.wait() but then there are two follow-up questions: 1. Why isn't that mentioned in the python docs and 2. Isn't it necessary that lhs has finished before rhs.communicate() can return? rhs.communicate() waits for the second process to finish but it shouldn't be able to finish before lhs has told it that no more data will follow.